# combine lists in a certain order c#

Tags: c#, list, winforms, math, combining-marks

I have winform project in c# that makes math operations. The string comes like `"=B10+B4*(B12-B8)"`.
And `B10` represents "3", `B4` represents "10" `B12` represent "6" and `B8` represent "2".
I want to convert this string to `"=3+10*(6-2)"`. So math operation can be happened.
For solution I created three list. I succeded to make operatorList and numberRepresentList as seen below.
My problem is combining this two list with a specific order.

```
List<string> operatorList= new List<string>();
List<string> numberRepresentList = new List<string>();
List<string> mergedList= new List<string>();


operatorList={"=","+","*","(","-",")"}
numberRepresentList =={"3","10","6","2"}
```

How can i combine them with a specific order so the result will shown as:

```
mergedList={"=","3","+","10","*","(","6","-","2",")"}
```

I have searched in forms but i can not find similar one. So i created one. Thanx in advance.

Edited:
Thanx to @vivek nuna.
I made a list name partOfString

```
 comesFromUser="=B10+B4*(B12-B8)"
 partofString={"B10","B4","B12","B8"}
 numberRepresentList =={"3","10","6","2"}
    
    for (int i = 0; i < partOfString.Count; i++)
        {
         comesFromUser = comesFromUser.Replace(partOfString[i], numberRepresentList[i]);
        }
```

Comment: You need a parser/lexer, a bit beyond the scope of [so]

Comment: @Charlieface Why is it beyond the scope of SO? If he can formulate a code problem, surely that's on-topic for SO? As long as it's reasonably scoped to a concrete question.

Comment: @Gokhan why did you choose to split the input string into two separate lists? Doing that you are losing the information about where the *tokens* are positioned

Comment: @Xerillio. Thanx for your attention.I have to split string. Because, for example in B10: "B" represent datagridview Column Name. "10" represent row index number. So B10 is a dataGridView Cell that it's value is "3". I'm trying to make excel operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be many ways to solve this problem.

The simplest approach, you can do this.

```
string output = input.Replace("B10", "3").Replace("B4", "10").Replace("B12", "6").Replace("B8", "2");
```